# Manually compute the sum of squares of a quadratic term in the fitted model.

Tags: regression, anova

Given the following data from the textbook, one may obtain the ANOVA table for the response surface quadratic model (as shown in the picture) using Design-Expert. I understand that the sum of squares of the linear terms and interaction terms can be obtained using the equation (contrast)$^{2/8n}.$ However, could anyone explain how the sum of squares for the quadratic terms are obtained?
[Raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTGrJ.png),
[ANOVA by Design-Expert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Up0F5.png)